# Calcular e converter tamanho de um arquivo de byte para kB, MB, GB, etc

Tags: php

Ola gostaria de saber como posso complementar o código abaixo para que o filesize via URL remota retorne o resultado do tamanho do arquivo em `MB` pois o código atual esta retornando o resultado do tamanho do arquivo em `bytes`.

```
function remotefileSize($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $filesize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($filesize) return $filesize;
}


echo remotefileSize('http://thumb.mais.uol.com.br/15233302-medium.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente é importante definir que KB **NÂO** é 1024, isso já foi resolvido há muito tempo.

Para evitar confusões, pois Kilo significa 1000, definiram o prefixo Kibi que possui o multiplicador 1024. Logo, temos o KiB, MiB, GiB e em alguns sistemas operacionais já estão usando as unidades corretas.
[IEC Standard Prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#IEC_standard_prefixes)

Agora quanto ao código, para poder converter para unidades arbitrárias:

```
function ConverterPrefixoBinario ($Valor, $UnidadeOrigem, $UnidadeDestino, $Precisão = 2)
{
    $Unidades = array (
        'B' => 1, 
        'KB' => 1000, 'MB' => 1000000, 'GB' => 1000000000, 'TB' => 1000000000,
        'KiB' => 1024, 'MiB' => 1048576, 'GiB' => 1073741824, 'TiB' => 1099511627776
    );

    $ValorBytes = $Valor * $Unidades [$UnidadeOrigem];

    return round($ValorBytes / $Unidades [$UnidadeDestino], $Precisão) . $UnidadeDestino;
}

// 0,15GiB
echo ConverterPrefixoBinario (150, 'MiB', 'GiB');

// 1,5MiB
echo ConverterPrefixoBinario (1572864, 'B', 'MiB');
```

Comment: É importante também salientar que é um tanto imprudente afirmar dessa forma, referente a KiB e KB. Apesar da existência do padrão IEC, não há nada de errado em apresentar KB como "kilobyte", o qual também é apresentado como somente "K", informalmente no mundo tecnológico. E mais, pelo padrão JEDEC, kb é 1024.  Na prática, o padrão IEC referente ao assunto, é inútil e ignorado pela indústria, exceto pelo OS-X, sistema operacional da Apple. Enfim, esse é um assunto um tanto fora do escopo da pergunta. Claro que é interessante, porém, acho que deveria ter um tópico específico para tal discussão.

Comment: Imprudente é utilizar uma unidade onde as pessoas possam interpretar de forma errada, JEDEC alerta sobre isso: The specification notes that these prefixes are included in the document only to reflect common usage. It refers to the IEEE/ASTM SI 10-1997 standard as stating, that "this practice frequently leads to confusion and is deprecated".

Comment: jesuis.........

Comment: Peça para 10 pessoas sem conhecimento em T.I. e outras 10 que são iniciantes em programação para converter Byte para KByte... o KiB foi criado para evitar essas confusões. Quanto a ser inútil na indústria, basta olhar que nem todos os fabricantes de HD utilizam base 1024 (faz alguns anos que não vejo HDs utilizando essa base, eu mesmo tenho um SSD de 120GB Kingston que é ~111GiB).

Comment: sasinhora......

Answer (score 1):

A base de cálculo é 1024 pois 1kb equivale a 1024 bytes.

Com base nisso, crie uma função que determine o tipo de medida.

```
/*
    1024000 bytes = 1 kilobytes
    1000 kb = 1 megabyte
    1000 mb = 1 gigabyte
    e assim vai..
*/
    function filesize_formatted($path)
    {
        $size = filesize($path);
        $units = array( 'B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB');
        $power = $size > 0 ? floor(log($size, 1024)) : 0;
        return number_format($size / pow(1024, $power), 2, '.', ',') . ' ' . $units[$power];
    }

    echo filesize_formatted( 2048 );
```

Nesse exemplo, a fim de reduzir o código, usamos uma função matemática do PHP chamada `pow()`, a qual faz cálculos de expressão potencial.

Importante, nesse exemplo retorna o resultado formatado com 2 casas decimais.
A formatação do resultado pode variar com a necessidade de cada um. Portanto, esteja ciente e modifique de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Sendo mais específico, referente ao seu código, remova todo o trecho desnecessário:

```
// Pega o tamanho do arquivo remoto
$tamanhoarquivo = $filesize;

//
$medidas = array('KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB');

/* Se for menor que 1KB arredonda para 1KB */
if($tamanhoarquivo < 999){
$tamanhoarquivo = 1024;
}

for ($i = 0; $tamanhoarquivo > 999; $i++){
$tamanhoarquivo /= 1024;
}

return round($tamanhoarquivo) . $medidas[$i - 1];
```

Troque por isso:

```
    function filesize_formatted($path)
    {
        $size = filesize($path);
        $units = array( 'B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB');
        $power = $size > 0 ? floor(log($size, 1024)) : 0;
        return number_format($size / pow(1024, $power), 2, '.', ',') . ' ' . $units[$power];
    }

    return filesize_formatted( $filesize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Se o resultado atual estava retornando em bytes era só dividir o resultado por 1048576 e você teria em MB

```
$tamanhoarquivo = $filesize;     /*Retorna o tamanho do arquivo em bytes*/
```

Logo:

```
$tamanhoarquivo = $filesize/1024;     /*Retorna o tamanho do arquivo em kbytes*/

$tamanhoarquivo = $filesize/1048576;  /*Retorna o tamanho do arquivo em Megabytes*/
```

Answer (score -1):

Creio que cheguei a uma solução deixo aqui o código para quem quiser usar. Desde já agradeço ao  Daniel Gomes pelas orientações nos comentários.

Caso alguém tenha alguma forma mais simplificada ou diferente fique a vontade em colocar sua resposta pois isso ira me ajudar nos meus estudos em php.

```
<?php 


    // Função que verifica o tamanho do arquivo remoto via url

    function remotefileSize($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $filesize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Pega o tamanho do arquivo remoto
    $tamanhoarquivo = $filesize;

    //
    $medidas = array('KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB');

    /* Se for menor que 1KB arredonda para 1KB */
    if($tamanhoarquivo < 999){
    $tamanhoarquivo = 1024;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $tamanhoarquivo > 999; $i++){
    $tamanhoarquivo /= 1024;
    }

    return round($tamanhoarquivo) . $medidas[$i - 1];
    }

    echo 'O tamamnho do arquivo da url http://thumb.mais.uol.com.br/15233302-medium.jpg e '.remotefileSize('http://thumb.mais.uol.com.br/15233302-medium.jpg');



?>
```

Comment: isso está errado.. 1kb equivale a 1024 bytes.. porém, na comparação verifica se for maior que 999.. .. outro ponto super estranho é o laço de repetição.. sem sentido algum.. e também o round() que torna o resultado menos impreciso..  que locura..

Comment: teria como dar uma ajuda postando uma resposta de como deve ser então ? Pois no caso deu o tamanho exato do arquivo para mim aqui.

Comment: @Rodrigo Veja [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2510459/1242661)

Comment: 1Kb não é 1024, KiB é 1024, coloquei na minha resposta como fazer conversão entre unidades diferentes.

Comment: O método do @DanielOmine está perfeito.