# Como abreviar/formatar números em php, como no YouTube?

Tags: php

Ex: 10000 vira 10k, 1000000 vira 1M e assim por diante?

Bem, eu fiz da seguinte forma. Se alguém tiver uma forma melhor e mais prática, por favor, me informe:

```
function abrevNmr($numero){     
        switch(strlen($numero)){
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                    return $numero;
                break;
            case 4: 
                    $num = str_split($numero, 1);
                    return $num[0].($num[1] > 0 ? ','.$num[1] : null).'k';
                break;
            case 5:
                    $num = str_split($numero, 1);
                    return $num[0].$num[1].($num[2] > 0 ? ','.$num[2] : null).'k';
                break;
            case 6:
                    $num = str_split($numero, 1);
                    return $num[0].$num[1].$num[2].($num[3] > 0 ? ','.$num[3] : null).'k';
                break;
            case 7:
                    $num = str_split($numero, 1);
                    return $num[0].($num[1] > 0 ? ','.$num[1] : null).'mi';
                break;
            case 8:
                    $num = str_split($numero, 1);
                    return $num[0].$num[1].($num[2] > 0 ? ','.$num[2] : null).'mi';
                break;
        }
    }
```

Ela vai até 99 milhões, porque isso já mais que suficiente para o que quero.

Comment: qual é a regra completa? 10000 vira 10k, ok, mas e 10896, continua sendo 10k? Ou vira 11? 10,5? e se for 1.960.526,23? É 1M? 2M? 1,96M?

Comment: Além do link do topo, [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81831) também tem um caso parecido, e [esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38880) também mostra a lógica que faz isso (só que em js)